# How do I give my simple java program memory?

Tags: java, memory, persistence

I am new to programming and I have a simple program I am working on for fun that keeps track of my money. For instance, I want it to record how much money is in my wallet. So I will give it some data, and it complies. However, when I rerun the program at a different time to add or subtract money from my wallet for example, it will revert back to 0 instead of saving the changes I made before.

I assume I have to make a txt file for this data to save to, and then have it read it every time I run the program?

```
//here is my wallet class
public class Wallet extends UserInterface{

    public String WalletName;
    public double WalletCash;

    public Wallet(String name) {
        this.WalletName = name;

    }

    public String addCashtoWallet(double income) {
        WalletCash += income;
        return "Added $" + income + "to " + this.WalletName;
    }

    public String removeCashfromWallet(double cost) {
        WalletCash -= cost;
        return "Removed $" + cost + "from " + this.WalletName;
    }

}
```

The output when I add money to the wallet for example, will be
"Your wallet now has $64.0 would you like to do anything else"
However, when I run the program again, it will say 0, but I want it to display the 64 dollars I added before. How do I get it to save this data?

Comment: yes, you have to store value in a file, otherwise whenever program is ran publicdouble WalletCash is always initialized on program start as 0.0

Comment: you can also use [`Preferences`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.prefs/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) to save that, kind of different but easy

Comment: Memory is the wrong term here, as that has [a specific meaning](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory). The technical terms you want are writing data to disk or drive, accessing a database, or more generally, persisting data to storage.

Comment: This kind of question too broad for Stack Overflow. Seek a discussion site such as http://www.JavaRanch.com

Answer (score 0):

You could use a file to keep your information and load the information at the startup.

https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-java/

Or you can use a database to keep that information.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

I advice you first to try to use a file, after that you could try using a database (e.g. MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 0):

It's not 'memory', it's called 'persistent storage'.

And simple TXT file is a worst solution, like for me. I suggest you to use at least structured file like JSON, but better - an embedded database like HSQLDB.